# How to create countdown component with React-Native and Moment.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, momentjs

I am creating simple countdown component with React-Native, for date formatting I am using `moment.js`, I am getting data from API call  in seconds format, then providing to child component, I want to transform this kind of data `121` into `2:01`, How to use moment to achieve this result and do not kill performance?

```js
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import moment from "moment";
import React, { useEffect, useState} from "react";
import { View, Text} from "react-native";
const Timer: React.FC<{ expirationDate: number,focus:boolean, loading:boolean}> = ({ expirationDate, focus, loading}) => {
    const [inactive, setIncative] = useState(false);
    const [timerCount, setTimer] = useState<number>(0) //can be any     number provided from props
    useEffect(() => {
        setTimer((prev:number)=> (expirationDate))
        let interval = setInterval(() => {
          setTimer(lastTimerCount => {
              lastTimerCount <= 1 && clearInterval(interval)
              return lastTimerCount - 1
          })
        }, 1000) 
        return () => clearInterval(interval)
      }, [loading]);
    return (
        <View
            style={{
                backgroundColor: expirationDate < 300 || inactive ? "#edbcbc" : "#cee5f4",
                width: 70,
                borderRadius: 7,
                paddingVertical: 6,
                flexDirection: "row",
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "center",
                position: "relative",
            }}
        >
            <View style={{ position: "relative", left: 4 }}>
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="timer-outline" size={13} color={expirationDate < 300 || inactive ? "#f54c4c" : "#004978"} />
            </View>
            //line sholud be changed
            <Text>{moment.duration(timerCount).format("h:mm")}</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

export default Timer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solotion: using `moment utc method` and transform state value into miliseconds

```js
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import moment from "moment";
import React, { useEffect, useState} from "react";
import { View, Text} from "react-native";
const Timer: React.FC<{ expirationDate: number,focus:boolean, loading:boolean}> = ({ expirationDate, focus, loading}) => {
    const [inactive, setIncative] = useState(false);
    const [timerCount, setTimer] = useState<number>(0)
    useEffect(() => {
        setTimer((prev:number)=> (expirationDate))
        let interval = setInterval(() => {
          setTimer(lastTimerCount => {
              lastTimerCount <= 1 && clearInterval(interval)
              return lastTimerCount - 1
          })
        }, 1000) 
        return () => clearInterval(interval)
      }, [loading]);
    return (
        <View
            style={{
                backgroundColor: expirationDate < 300 || inactive ? "#edbcbc" : "#cee5f4",
                width: 70,
                borderRadius: 7,
                paddingVertical: 6,
                flexDirection: "row",
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "center",
                position: "relative",
            }}
        >
            <View style={{ position: "relative", left: 4 }}>
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="timer-outline" size={13} color={expirationDate < 300 || inactive ? "#f54c4c" : "#004978"} />
            </View>
            <Text>{moment.utc(timerCount * 1000).format("mm:ss")}</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

export default Timer;
```